Tracking dependent reactions and reactants using stoichiometric matrix for a very complex system of equations
I am modeling a metabolic network of signaling pathways through a system of ordinary differential equations
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = F(X) = S v
$$
where $X$ is the vector of molecules (121 in my case) involved in the system, $(F_i)_i$ is the vector right hand side (production of $X_i$ - consumption of $X_i$), $S$ is the stoichiometric matrix, and $v$ is the vector of reaction rate (111 reactions in my case). My goal is to study the stability of the system, it happens that the Jacobian of the system is singular, this is why I thought that using the stoichiometric matrix is a good idea.
Now, I start by defining the rank of $S$ ($r=93$ in my case). Next, I would like to track the dependent reactions so I can obtain a new reduced system that will have a full rank non singular Jacobian. To do so, I used the SVD decomposition of $S = U \Sigma V^T$, but I don't know how to project the matrix $S$ into the first $r$ columns of $U$ (or $V$) to obtain indices of dependent reactions.
